# AVX2 vectorized 256 bit lookup table (32 unsigned chars)

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I'm new to AVX intrinsics (and AVX in general) and I'm attempting to speed up some code that is using a 256 bit lookup table consisting of 32 unsigned chars.  Currently the code (with dummy data) is written as such:

```
unsigned char lookup_table[32] = { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 };
unsigned char result[8];
unsigned char indices[8] = { 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28};
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    result[i] = lookup_table[indices[i]];
}
```

Which works fine and results in the following being placed into "result":

```
0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28
```

In attempt to speed this up, I've replaced the above code with the following AVX instructions:

```
unsigned char lookup_table[32] = { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 };
unsigned char result[8];
unsigned char indices[8] = { 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28};
__m256i avxTable = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&table);
__m256i avxIndices = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&indices);

__m256i avxResult= _mm256_shuffle_epi8(avxTable , avxIndices);
```

Which results in the following output:

```
0, 4, 8, 12, 0, 4, 8, 12
```

What I've gathered is that the _mm256_shuffle_epi8 instrinsic ANDs the indices with 0X0F (according to the psuedocode at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524017), effectively making any indices above 16 "wrap around" again, hence the repeat of the (0, 4, 8, 12).

Am I using the wrong AVX call?  Am I totally off base with the way I believe this should work?

Comment: This isn't going to work. You could try using gather-instructions, but those load at least 32-bit blocks, so the efficiency would be questionable, especially on Haswell where gather instructions are slow anyway.

Comment: The general idea is sound, but you need to be aware that the shuffle is really 2 x 128 bit operations rather than a proper 256 bit shuffle (like many other AVX instructions). The solution will be rather more complex than the above code, but it should still be more efficient than scalar code.

Comment: You are actually better off doing 2 x 128 bit SSE shuffles, and use bit 4 to select the final output from the two 16 way lookups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using SSE rather than AVX. Note that it performs 16 lookups in parallel (you can't do fewer than this with 128 bit SIMD and 8 bit elements):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <smmintrin.h> // SSE 4.1

int main()
{
    unsigned char lookup_table[32] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                                       16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 };

    unsigned char result[16];
    unsigned char indices[16] = { 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30 };

    __m128i vIndices, vSelect, vTable0, vTable1, vResult0, vResult1, vResult;

    vIndices = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&indices);
    vSelect = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(vIndices,  _mm_set1_epi8(15));
    vTable0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&lookup_table[0]);
    vTable1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&lookup_table[16]);
    vResult0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vTable0, vIndices);
    vResult1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vTable1, vIndices);
    vResult = _mm_blendv_epi8(vResult0, vResult1, vSelect);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)result, vResult);

    printf("%vd\n", vResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ gcc -Wall test_lut.c -msse4 && ./a.out 
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 2 6 10 14 18 22 26 30
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul, this was incredibly helpful (and works perfectly!).  Based on your earlier comments I had gotten as far as realizing I needed to form a mask indicating which indices were greater than 16, but had no idea the blendv instruction was out there, which was the missing piece for me.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Paul R What would you suggest if I have lookup table of 2048 elements?

Comment: @StNickolay: if you have AVX2 then use gathered loads, otherwise you’re probably out of luck.

Comment: @Paul R Do you mean, it doesn't make sense to implement complex logic with SSE and use just plain C code?

Comment: @StNickolay: yes, for larger LUT operations you’ll get less and less benefit from SIMD as the table size grows. For 2048 you’re probably past the tipping point.

Comment: Would the equivalent approach work for a 64 element table using 256bit intrinsics?

Comment: @jregalad: yes, although it gets trickier than just expanding the above 128 bit SSE code, as most AVX2 shuffle/permute instructions are split-lane, i.e. 2 x 128 bit wide rather than 256 bit wide.